# Have you seen this weird QoQ Error [ColdFusion]?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, qoq

I have confirmed that the first query works as expected

```
<cfquery name="validation_info" dbtype="query">
    select      shipViaName,TOTALSHIPRATE
    from        s_c_c.qShipCalc
    WHERE       sku in (#preserveSingleQuotes(validate)#)
</cfquery>
<cfquery name="validation_info2" dbtype="query">
    select      TOTALSHIPRATE
    from        validation_info
    WHERE       shipViaName = "FedEx 3 Day"
</cfquery>
```

But on the second query, I get this error:

> Encountered "shipViaName. Incorrect conditional expression, Incorrect
>   conditional expression, Lexical error at line 0, column 0.
>   Encountered: "\"" (34), after : ""

It says the error is happening on this line:

```
<cfquery name="validation_info2" dbtype="query">
```

I was also getting this error when I had the two queries combined into one.

**Update from comments:**

Dump of the validation_info query:

SHIPVIANAME TOTALSHIPRATE

```
1 | FedEx Ground | 11.9  ||
2 | FedEx 3 Day  | 22.99 || 
3 | FedEx 2 Day  | 26.99 || 
4 | FedEx 1 Day  | 44.55 || 
5 | FedEx Ground | 0     || 
6 | FedEx 3 Day  | 23.63 || 
7 | FedEx 2 Day  | 26.71 || 
8 | FedEx 1 Day  | 41.9  ||
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of what is in validate? And a sample of what is in validation_info?

Comment: Have you tried single quotes in the second query? As an aside, I would recommend using cfqueryparam in your QoQ's. Since your first query uses a list of values, tack on the `list` attribute ie `WHERE SKU IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#validate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true">) `.

Comment: validation_info
  SHIPVIANAME TOTALSHIPRATE
1 | FedEx Ground | 11.9 ||
2 | FedEx 3 Day | 22.99 ||
3 | FedEx 2 Day | 26.99 ||
4 | FedEx 1 Day | 44.55 ||
5 | FedEx Ground | 0 ||
6 | FedEx 3 Day |23.63 ||
7 | FedEx 2 Day | 26.71 ||
8 | FedEx 1 Day | 41.9 ||

Comment: HOLY S#*@! Single quotes worked! WTF?!

Comment: (Edit) Typically the jdbc convention is to use single (not double) quotes. But using `cfqueryparam`, instead of messing with quotes, avoids the whole issues altogether. It handles everything for you.

Comment: @Leigh Can you post this as an answer so I can give you credit? Also, for some reason cfqueryparam wasn't working, I've used it a million times before, so I don't know what was going on, probably some weird scoping issue, but that's why I didn't use cfqueryparam, and I was too under the gun to figure it out.

Comment: @TravisHeeter - Appreciated, but feel free to accept KRC's answer as we both came to the same conclusion around the same time :) Just glad you figured out the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use single quotes instead of double quotes for your string in your second SQL query.

Comment: Of course, I missed seeing this suggestion in the comments of the post.

Comment: Haha, no worries. If I had wanted to make it an answer I would have :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `cfqueryparam` for your variables, try this

```
<cfquery name="validation_info" dbtype="query">
    SELECT      
        shipViaName,
        TOTALSHIPRATE
    FROM        
        s_c_c.qShipCalc
    WHERE       
        sku IN (<cfqueryparam value="#validate#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" list="yes" /> )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: *hopefully preserveSingleQuotes doesn't return a list* [PreserveSingleQuotes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6cbf.html) stops CF from automatically protecting the query by doubling single quotes. So using cfqueryparam instead is definitely the way to go. Even with QoQ's.

Comment: @Leigh I didn't realize that it was a function build into CF.

Comment: Yep. But it is not used much anymore because it presents a sql injection risk in *database* queries.